# Auto-Increment using different databases

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using Spring and JPA with Java 7. I wrote my code originally using mySQL and am now migrating to SQLServer for some installations. Unfortunately, the auto-increment Identity methodology  is different. Is there a preferred way to preserve both methods? I really would prefer not to branch just for this one thing.
Thx

Comment: Are you auto-generating the schema, or using SQL scripts? If you are using SQL scripts - I would strongly recommend using db script execution manager like *liquibase*, so you could have different scripts for both DBs. E.g. for Oracle you would need to create a trigger, while MySQL as well as MS SQL have auto-increment built in - the script will generate the right SQL, and you can also have profiles for different DBs

Comment: Firstly IDENTITY JPA strategy implies use "auto increment", which means "AUTOINCREMENT" for MySQL and "IDENTITY" for SQLServer, so not sure why you have a problem with using that. Secondly the easiest way to separate such things is to put RDBMS specific info in orm.xml and have one orm.xml for MySQL and one orm.xml for SQLServer

Answer (score 0):

If you used @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) for that auto-increment column, then you just need to change your JPA( or Hibernate) configuration to use proper dialect.

e.g, from org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ( for mysql5) 
to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect(mssql)

Comment: AUTO says "let the JPA provider choose the strategy". It does not imply that IDENTITY will be used (and hence auto-generated). The ONLY way to guarantee auto-generated is to use IDENTITY explicitly.

Comment: I am using @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tx_id") The issue is that for mySQL, the way that

Comment: I specify that I want an auto-incremented value is to specify the value as 0 (or in this case, it is a Long so it is 0L). But with SQLServer, my understanding is that you don't specify it at all and leave it null. So in my code, when I call the Controller to insert a row, I am currently passing in that 0. Are you saying that I can always pass in 0 or null from my code if I change the annotation?